# If statements and conditions

Tags: javascript, acrobat

I am trying to confirm two different things in an alert box, if statement. The first is that the user pressed the yes button and the second is a user input value on the page. See the code below. I'm still pretty green, any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
var cMsg = "You are about to reset this page!";
cMsg += "\n\nDo you want to continue?";

var nRtn = app.alert(cMsg,2,2,"Question Alert Box");
if(nRtn == 4) && (getField("MV").value == 5)
{
////// do this

}
else if(nRtn == 4) && (getField("MV").value == 6)
{
/////then do this
}
else if(nRtn == 4) && (getField("MV").value == 7)
{
/////then do this
}

}
else if(nRtn == 3)
{
console.println("Abort the submit operation");
}
else
{ //Unknown Response
console.println("The Response Was somthing other than Yes/No: " + nRtn);
}
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Incorrect syntax first correct that, Use `if((nRtn == 4) && (getField("MV").value == 5))` if syntax is `if(condition)....`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your [if...else](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/if...else) syntax is incorrect. Correct syntax

```
if (condition)
   statement1
[else
   statement2]
```

*Use correct syntax*

```
if (nRtn == 4 && getField("MV").value == 5) {
    ////// do this    
} else if (nRtn == 4 && getField("MV").value == 6) {
    /////then do this
} else if (nRtn == 4 && getField("MV").value == 7) {
    /////then do this
} else if (nRtn == 3) {
    console.println("Abort the submit operation");
} else { //Unknown Response
    console.println("The Response Was somthing other than Yes/No: " + nRtn);
}
```

*instead of*

```
if (nRtn == 4) && (getField("MV").value == 5) {
    ////// do this

} else if (nRtn == 4) && (getField("MV").value == 6) {
    /////then do this
} else if (nRtn == 4) && (getField("MV").value == 7) {
    /////then do this
} <=== Remove this 

} else if (nRtn == 3) {
    console.println("Abort the submit operation");
} else { //Unknown Response
    console.println("The Response Was somthing other than Yes/No: " + nRtn);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you are trying to evaluate two different conditions that is:
    "nRtn" // value returned from app.alert(cMsg,2,2,"Question Alert Box");
    and: getField("MV").value.

However, the compiler will only process the first condition because the braces end there. You should make sure to enclose all conditions within one brace. Individual conditions can and by convention should be in separate braces too within the main brace.
The right way therefore should be:

```
if ((nRtn == 4) && (getField("MV").value == 5))
//notice the initial if (( and terminating ))
//You could have 3 conditions as follows
// if (((condition1) && (condition2)) && (condition3)))
{
////// do this

}
else if((nRtn == 4) && (getField("MV").value == 6))
{
/////then do this
}
else if((nRtn == 4) && (getField("MV").value == 7))
{
/////then do this
}

}
else if(nRtn == 3)
{
console.println("Abort the submit operation");
}
else
{ //Unknown Response
console.println("The Response Was somthing other than Yes/No: " + nRtn);
}
```